# Asp.net routing between different web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I am creating a website and I'm trying to implement routing feature. Most of the time it works fine, but I've found a problem while routing between different web forms placed at different levels from the root of the website.

[image]

The above picture shows all the routes defined and picture below shows the solution explorer of my project:

[image]

Home page(home.aspx) of my website is shown below:

[image]

On clicking the picture it opens a new page(singlepage.aspx) with whole article about the topic and contains the required url(sitename/heading/querystring):

[image]

But from there when i click on **HOME** button, it does not take me to home page, but instead gets me to the url like this:

[image]

Seems like it is not calling the "routeHome" route, instead calls "routeSinglePage".

This is how the html for taking us to HOME page is:

[image]

So I wanted to know how I can get it to the home page from singlepage.aspx by clicking on HOME button. Do I need to add new routes or something else.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the HTML to:

```
<li><a href="/Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/AbousUs">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/ContactUs">Contact</a></li>
```

The "/" indicates an absolute path, you are currently using a relative path and hence the issue.

Comment: No problem after that